# Why do I get an error while trying to install google-colab with pip?

Tags: python, installation, pip, google-colaboratory

I was trying to install google colab because I heard about it from a tutorial and wanted to play around with it to see exactly what it did. I did the "pip install google-colab" command.

When I did the "pip install google-colab" command it seemed to work fine at first, but it didn't finish and gave this error:

```
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      <string>:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I tried in the command prompt and in vscode and both gave the same answer. Is this a problem others are having or is it just me?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see on the [Official `google-colab` package page](https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/#description) it is only compatible with python2.7, 3.5 and 3.6.

All of which are dead, so you probably don't have the right version.

As such I would recommend avoiding this package since it doesn't seem to be maintained any longer (The homepage is not available either).